# Encriptación de contraseña con password_hash

Tags: php, encriptación

Mi consulta es que tengo un formulario de registro en el que se pide almacenar una contraseña, el formulario funciona correctamente y lo que sigue es `encriptar` la contraseña, ando utilizando la función `password_hash` sin embargo no consigo tener la sintaxis correcta para que al registrar la contraseña esta quede encriptada en la BD.

Adjunto el código `PHP`

```
<?php
//include "Conex1.php";

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "gesy_agro");

 echo "Conexion realizada";
 $sql= "INSERT INTO `documentacion_usuario` (`DocNombre`,`DocCedula`, `DocCorreo`, `DocDireccion`, `DocTelefono`, `DocUsuario`, `DocContraseña`) VALUES ('$_POST[Nombres]',$_POST[Cedula], '$_POST[Correo]', '$_POST[Direccion]', '$_POST[Telefono]', '$_POST[Usuario]', $_POST[Contraseña])";


    $password = password_hash($Contraseña, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 11]);
    echo "$password";

if (!mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
        echo "Error: ,". mysqli_error($conexion);


//$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
mysqli_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola te comento que revise tu pregunta y propongo el siguiente ejemplo donde puedo generar el `hash` correspondiente; luego entonces lo único que deberías hacer es pasar el nombre de la variable al `INSERT` SQL para que se almacene en la Base de Datos.

```
<?php
$name = '';

function store($name) 
{
    return password_hash($name, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
}

echo store('Alfredo');
```

y Te comento que me devuelve:

```
$2y$10$wv/mofEWT/KBqFlj4ENZRuhna6.d/TDGhTegVlVHBZ2O2XEcUuOp.
```

El segundo parámetro `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` es usado para crear nuevos hashes de un password usando el algoritmo `CRYPT_BLOWFISH`

Comment: Me funcionó, garcias :)

Comment: No es necesario tener un método adicional cuando el método ya es `password_hash` es decisión del autor de la pregunta aceptar la respuesta que mejor le parezca solo hay que tener en cuenta que esta respuesta no soluciona el problema de raíz y tampoco tiene en cuenta el grave fallo de seguridad al concatenar valores.

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar el proceso de `hashing` con la función  [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php) se realiza después de asignar los valores correctamente para la sentencia `SQL`. Tal y como está su código se añadirán los valores que llegan por `POST` , **Pero** . tiene problemas muy graves de seguridad al concatenar los valores a su consulta, presta a recibir [Ataques de Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php). En su lugar debe [preparar](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) la consulta para evitar estas fallas de seguridad.

**Ejm** *(posible código)*

```
$nombres = $_POST['Nombres'];
$cedula = $_POST['Cedula'];
$correo = $_POST['Correo'];
$direccion = $_POST['Direccion'];
$telefono = $_POST['Telefono'];
$usuario = $_POST['Usuario'];
//Encriptamos el valor de contrasenia
$contrasenia = password_hash($_POST['Contrasenia'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 11]);


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "gesy_agro");
// Tantos marcadores como campos en su base de datos  7 para su caso
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `documentacion_usuario` (`DocNombre`,`DocCedula`, `DocCorreo`, `DocDireccion`, `DocTelefono`, `DocUsuario`, `DocContraseña`) VALUES (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores ? , luego la S significa que será de tipo String  */
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $nombres,$cedula,$correo,$direccion,$telefono,$usuario,$contrasenia);
    /* ejecutar la consulta */
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

> Una consideración importante en mi ejemplo es el reemplazo de la letra
>   **ñ** tanto para el valor del `post` como para el nombre de campo de la base de datos `DocContrasenia` ya que el uso de esta puede traer
>   resultados inesperados, es por eso que debería reemplazar en su
>   `input` del `form` que envía los datos.

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias por la ayuda, en efecto me sirvio el código! ya logré encriptar la contraseña.