# Login usando PHP y MySql

Tags: php

Mi consulta es simple, tengo un archivo `PHP` por medio del cual registro los datos de un usuario nuevo entre esos "usuario" y "contraseña" y los guarda en una base de datos, cabe aclarar que la contraseña queda encriptada usando `password_hash`, ahora lo que requiero es hacer el `login`, que al ingresar el usuario y la contraseña antes registradas me de acceso a el contenido, el tema es que ando viendo vídeo tutoriales pero no me dan las pautas precisas para el inicio de sesión.

Vi este código y trate de usarlo más no sirvió.
Agradezco su ayuda y aportes!

```
<?php 
    $user = $_POST['user']; //así esta nombrado en el formulario
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; //así esta nombrado en el formulario

    if (empty($user) || empty($pass)) {
        header("location: inicio_sesion.php");
        exit();
    }

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','liz2125') or die ("Error al conectar" .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('gesyagro') or die ("Error al seleccionar la base de datos ".mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documentacion_usuario WHERE DocUsuario ='" .$user. "'");

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if ($row['pass'] == $pass) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header("location: contenido.php");
                }else{
                    header("location: inicio_sesion.php");
                    exit();
                }
            }else{
            header("location: inicio_sesion.php");


exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: En su [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139795/encriptaci%C3%B3n-de-contrase%C3%B1a-con-password-hash) utilizaba la extensión MySQLi y añadí una respuesta con consultas preparadas ? ¿Por qué regresar a una extensión **deprecated** como `Mysql`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno mira yo lo hice por partes primero lo de la interfaz, con alertas en la validación de los campos y también utilizo ajax

```html
...
</div>
                  <div class="text-center">
                      <label for="correo_electronico ">Correo Electrónico: </label>
                      <input type="text" name="correo_electronico" id="correo_electronico" />
                      <p id="alerta_correo_electronico" style="display:none; ">*El campo <b>Correo Electrónico</b> es obligatorio.</p>
                  </div>
                  
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <label for="contrasena">Contraseña:</label>
                      <input type="password" name="contrasena" id="contrasena" />
                      <p id="alerta_contrasena" style="display:none;">*El campo <b>Contraseña</b> es obligatorio.</p>
                  </div>  
                  <div class="text-center">   
                               
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"  value="ENTRAR" />                   
                    <div id="resultado"></div>
                </div>

...
    </form> 
        
    </div>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
    <div id="resultadoJson"></div> 
         <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){        
                $("#frmRegistrar").submit(function(event){ 
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                      url: "login_.php",
                      type: 'POST',
                      data: formData,
                      async: false,
                      cache: false,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false,
                      beforeSend : function (){
                       $("#resultado").fadeOut(200, function (){$("#resultado").html("<center><img border='0' src='images/loading.gif'></center>");});
                       $("#resultado").fadeIn(100);
                       },    
                      success: function (returndata) {
                          $("#resultado").fadeOut(300, function (){$("#resultado").html(returndata);});
                          $("#resultado").fadeIn(300);      
                      },
                      error: function (){
                       $("#resultado").fadeOut(200, function (){$("#resultado").html("<span class= \"error\">Ha ocurrido un error, inténtelo nuevamente</span>");});
                       $("#resultado").fadeIn(100);
                       }            
                    });
                    return false;
                });         
            }); 
      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Después en otro archivo las validaciones y valido en la bd los datos recibidos

```html
<?php
$correo_electronico=filter_var($_POST['correo_electronico'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$contrasena=filter_var($_POST['contrasena'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$grabar=TRUE;
$resultadoValidacion="";
echo"hola1";
if(!filter_var($correo_electronico,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $grabar=FALSE;
    $resultadoValidacion .= '$("#alerta_correo_electronico").show();';
}else{
    $resultadoValidacion .= '$("#alerta_correo_electronico").hide();';
}
echo"hola2";
if(empty($contrasena)){
    $grabar=FALSE;
    $resultadoValidacion .= '$("#alerta_contrasena").show();';
}else{
    $resultadoValidacion .= '$("#alerta_contrasena").hide();';
}

if($grabar){
    include_once 'consultas_login.php';
    $resultado=get_login($correo_electronico, $contrasena);
    
    if($resultado[0]['error']==0){
        
        if(count($resultado[1])>0){
            session_start(); 
           
            $_SESSION['id_usuario']=$resultado[1][0]['id_usuario'];
            
            $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$resultado[1][0]['nombre'] . " " . $resultado[1][0]['apellidos'];
            $_SESSION['id_rol']=$resultado[1][0]['id_rol'];
           
            $_SESSION['autenticado']=TRUE;

            echo "<script> window.location='index.php';</script>";


        }else{
        
            echo "<script>alert('Datos de acceso incorrectos');</script>"; 
        }
    }else{
        echo $resultado[1];
    }
    
}else{
   echo "<script>" . $resultadoValidacion . "</script>"; 
}
?>
```

Espero y te sirva de algo mi ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar la función `password_verify` de PHP para validar la contraseña que has almacenado en la base de datos con `password_hash`.

Tienes el siguiente parametro recibido de POST

```
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
```

Convertirás la contraseña a hash haciendo lo siguiente

```
$hashed_password = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Y almacenas la contraseña hash en tu base de datos (que hasta aquí ya lo hiciste). Bien, ahora un usuario desea iniciar sesión en tu web. Debes de hacer una query en tu MySQL.

```
// Query a la base de datos para traer la contraseña almacenada
// y compararla con la contraseña recibida por POST del formulario.

if(password_verify($pass, $hashed_password)) {
    // Si la contraseña coincide con la de la base de datos...
    // Haz algo, como iniciar sesión.
} 

// Si no, redirecciona a otro lugar o haz lo que creas conveniente.
```

Al final, quedaría algo como esto tomando tu ejemplo:

```
<?php 
    $user = $_POST['user']; //así esta nombrado en el formulario
    $pass = $_POST['pass']; //así esta nombrado en el formulario

    if (empty($user) || empty($pass)) {
        header("location: inicio_sesion.php");
        exit();
    }

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','liz2125') or die ("Error al conectar" .mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('gesyagro') or die ("Error al seleccionar la base de datos ".mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM documentacion_usuario WHERE DocUsuario ='" .$user. "'");

    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        //Comparo el hash que tengo en mi BDD con la contraseña normal
        //del formulario recibido por POST
        if (password_verify($pass, $row['pass'])) {
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header("location: contenido.php");
        }else{
            header("location: inicio_sesion.php");
            exit();
        }
    } else {
        header("location: inicio_sesion.php");
        exit();
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hola mira, pues yo en otro archivo .php tengo la insercion de los datos de registro y ahí estoy aplicando el password_default así:  $contrasenia = password_hash($_POST['Contrasenia'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT, ['cost' => 11]);  mi consulta es, esa variable $contrasenia se puede llamar al  otro archivo o debo volver a encriptar el valor de la contraseña para el login, saludos.

Comment: Acuerdate que password_hash es para registrar un usuario y encriptar su contraseña. Mientras que password_verify, sirve en un login y sirve para verificar la contraseña ingresada con la contraseña encriptada que esta en la base de datos.