# sesiones php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, validación, sesiones

Cordial saludo

buenos dias como hago para validar el perfil de un usuario en el controlador y en caso de ser docente o administrador me envie a la pagina respectiva tengo el siguiente codigo:
omo puedo hacer para que me redireccione a la pagina segun su perfil de usuario en base de datos tengo un campo tipo enum llamado perfil

codigo de controlador usuarios

```
<?php
 require_once('../Model/Usuarios.php');
 if($_POST){
     $Usuario=$_POST['Usuario'];
     $Pass=$_POST['Clave'];
     $Modelo = new Usuarios();
     if($Modelo->login($Usuario,$Pass))
     {
       header('Location:../../estudiantes/Pages/index.php');
      
     }else
     {
       
       header('Location:../../index.php');
         
     }
 }else{
     header('Location:../../index.php');
 }
```

```
 public function login($usuario , $pass){
            $rows =null;
            $statement =$this->db->prepare("SELECT *
             FROM users WHERE name=:usuario AND password= :pass ");
            $statement->bindParam(':usuario',$usuario);
            $statement->bindParam(':pass',$pass);
            $statement->execute();
            //condicional
            if($statement->rowCount()==1)
            {
                $result=$statement->fetch(); 
                $_SESSION['nom']= $result["name"]."\n".$result['last_name'];
                $_SESSION['id']= $result["users_id"];
                $_SESSION['rol']=$result["perfil"];
                //."".$result["last_name"]
                return true;
                
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Donde tienes la redirección para estudiantes analiza $_SESSION['rol'] y redirecciona a la página que corresponda, de acuerdo al valor. Pregunta: ¿Estás guardando las contraseñas sin encriptar? Es una mala práctica porque facilitas el trabajo de hackers/crackers.

Comment: como puedo encriptar la clave

Comment: Revisa las respuestas de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/139795/encriptaci%c3%b3n-de-contrase%c3%b1a-con-password-hash)